# How to enable webcam for Dell Precision 7510?

Tags: dell, webcam

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on **Dell Precision 7510** and it doesn't detect properly built-in webcam. Webcam is enabled in BIOS and this laptop doesn't have dedicated **FN+?** keys to manage Webcam.

If I try to run `cheese` I'm getting

```
** Message: cheese-application.vala:211: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:5622): cheese-CRITICAL **: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:5622): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:5622): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5622): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:5622): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

** (cheese:5622): CRITICAL **: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed
```

`lsusb` returns

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2516:0011  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5805 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

From [Dell's support page](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/precision-m7510-workstation/Prec7510_OM-v1/Technical-specification?guid=GUID-C8ED19D1-97BB-441C-B0D7-49FD9D5ED312&lang=en-us) I was able to get some details about built-in camera, but those don't tell me much

```
Table 12. CameraFeature Specification
Type    CMOS Sensor
Still Resolution    1280 x 720 Pixels ( Maximum )
Video Resolution    1280 x 720 Pixels @ 30 Frame Per Seconds ( Maximum )
Diagonal    74 degrees
```

`/dev/video*` file(s) don't exist neither

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```